# I need to broadcost Httprequest in diffrent sources in java

Tags: java, httprequest

I need to  create child http-request(broadcost) on the basis of single client request, and when child request will end then it inform to main request.

how could i implement this . will you all provide the better idea in java .

Regards

Nilay Tiwari

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a method which handles the client HTTP request, then you would make the child HTTP request synchronously in that method. The child request will return response and you can then choose what response to return to the client.

To make the HTTP request, you could use [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in the JDK, or the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library.

Comment: Yes i understand , i think i need to clear it more , actually i want to create child thread of that request,first child thread which is complete  early that  will send client response,after that last thread will complete that will again response to client. OR completion on every child thread that will response to client

Comment: An HTTP request can only have one response. You can block completion until all child requests finish. Or you can return response immediately and let child requests complete asynchronously. In latter case, your client could issue further requests (maybe XmlHttpRequests?) to check status.